# How to make a method that takes an array of integers and returns the avg number?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int, average

```
System.out.println(type integer);
int 1 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println(type integer);
int 2 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println(type integer);
int 3 = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println(type integer);
int 4 = kb.nextInt();
int [] integers = new int {1 + 2 + 3 + 4}
System.out.println(integers / numberofinputs?);
```

yeah i dont know how to divide the total sum by the amount of numbers inside the array.

Comment: There is not even a single line without an error in it. Didn't you even try to compile anything?

Answer (score 3):

***Question:***

> how to make a method that takes an array of integers and returns the
>   avg number?

***Answer:***

```
public static double getAverage(int[] array)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : array) sum += i;
    return ((double) sum)/array.length;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will truncate the decimals off of the average.  For example, the "average" of 2, 3, and 5, will be `3` instead of `3.3333....`.  Cast to a double before dividing to avoid truncation.

Comment: @Jonathan can't _just_ cast to a `double`, since the function is declared to return `int`.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis You are right!

Comment: yet when i compile this code nothing outputs. Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Recursively

```
double getAverage ( int [ ] array )
{
    return ( double ) ( getSum ( array , 0 , array . length ) ) / array . length ;
}

int getSum ( int [ ] array , int floor , int ceil )
{
    if ( ceil - floor < 1 ) { throw new RuntimeException ( ) ; }
    else if ( ceil - floor == 1 )
    {
         return array [ floor ] ;
    }
    else
    {
         return getSum ( floor , ( floor + ceil ) / 2 ) + getSum ( ( floor + ceil ) / 2 , ceil ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... Holy crap. Didn't see this answer coming.

Answer (score 0):

To try and steer you in the right direction, you will want to try and break this up into parts. I suggest making a listing of all of the things you will need to do to complete this task.

- Get the values to compute the average of, saving them into an array.

  - This will require knowing where the data is coming from (a file, typed, etc).
  - It may also require knowing how many values will be given when the program is run.
- Go through the array one element of the time, computing the sum of all of the values.

  - You can do this by following Eng.Fouad's example.
- Once you have the sum, simply divide by the amount of values that were input into the program. This is your final average.

The biggest issue it looks like you're have is trying to get the values from the user. You're on the right track using a Scanner (I assume from standard input, or the command line) but now you need to save multiple values into an array (or a list or something).

I'll give you an example using an array (this will require knowing how many values are going to be provided though). NOTE - This *will not compile*. You have to fill in the details before attempting to get this to function properly.

```
Scanner scanner = ... ; # Fill in the '...'
int totalElements = 10;  # TODO - Determine what this value should be, or get it from the user
double[] values = new double[totalElements]; # Make an array with totalElements amount of slots
int counter = 0;

while (/* fill this in with scanner method to check for another double*/) {
    values[counter] = /* fill in with scanner method to read a double*/;
    /* fill in with a way to increase the counter by 1 */
}
```

From here, you can begin to work on a function to compute the average.